# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <module> on importlib import_module

Tags: python, module

I am trying to create a module hooker, that corrects module name while importing a module, here is the small prototype:

```
from sys import meta_path, modules
from importlib import import_module


class Hook:
    spellcheck = {"maht": "math", "randon": "random", "ramdom": "random"}

    def find_module(self, module, _):
        if module in self.spellcheck:
            return self

    def load_module(self, module):
        modules[module] = import_module(self.spellcheck[module])
        return modules[module]


meta_path.clear()
meta_path.append(Hook())

import randon
import maht
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yagiz/Desktop/spellchecker.py", line 20, in <module>
    import randon
  File "/home/yagiz/Desktop/spellchecker.py", line 13, in load_module
    modules[module] = import_module(self.spellcheck[module])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'random'
```

Current machine, ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.6.9 also i tried with newer versions of python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about `meta_path.clear()`, just remove it.

By using the `clear` function, you are clearing `meta_path` from the builtin modules, so even the builtin module `random` couldn't be loaded.

**Edit:**

As discussed through comments, you can provide a misspelling error message instead of accepting loading the misspelled module. This can be done by updating your `Hook` class to:

```
class Hook:
    spellcheck = {"maht": "math", "randon": "random", "ramdom": "random"}
    def find_module(self, module, _):
        if module in self.spellcheck:
            return self
    def load_module(self, module):
        raise ImportError(f"No module named '{module}'. Did you mean '{self.spellcheck[module]}'?")
```

Now, if you import one of the misspelled modules:

```
import randon
```

Output:

```
ImportError: No module named 'randon'. Did you mean 'random'?
```

Comment: There's still a bug where `random` is not recognized.  You've imported the `random` package but your scripts still refer to the misspelled `randon` name.  I'm not sure what the right fix is, but this is probably not a full solution.

Comment: Do you want to import `randon` and then use `random` in your script later? How come!

Comment: I think OP wants to accidentally `import randon` and then later in the script call `random.randint(1,2)` and have no errors.  At least that's what I assume.  If that's the case then there is still more work to be done on this script.

Comment: Let me theoretically agree on what you said, then let's think about the issues behind that. It is not appropriate to call a misspelled module and then use the correct name later. Your code now is confusing, unreadable, and misleading.

Comment: I'm in complete agreement with your concerns. I think a more appropriate solution in this case would be to fail on the spelling mistake and provide suggestions at runtime: `No module named 'randon'. Did you mean 'random'?` That being said, there might an application (like a repl) where it's not such a big deal to assume the user wants the spelling error automatically corrected.  My comments were just about trying to interpret the OP's original question.

Comment: providing a misspelling suggestion at runtime is a good solution. I have edited my answer with this part.